# how add react component to a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a vanilla rails 5 application with no extra gems installed.

I do to do things like this

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused; do you have `gem 'react-rails'` installed?

Comment: I can add it. Then what.

Answer (score 0):

give [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem a try. The doc is simple to follow.